Can we use InitializeComponent() in the OnAppearing method in .NET MAUI?
I’m working on a .NET MAUI application where I’ve encountered an issue related to navigation flow and component initialization.
Here’s the scenario:

When the app is launched for the first time, it navigates to the HomePage before login, due to the login process being handled via deep linking.

As expected, InitializeComponent() is called from the constructor of HomePage during the initial app launch.

After login, the app again navigates to HomePage (since it's set as the initial page post-login), but this time, the constructor of HomePage is not called, and hence, the data retrieved from a service (which is supposed to populate the UI components) doesn't bind, leaving some components blank.


To address this, I registered HomePage using AddTransient, expecting that the constructor would be invoked again upon navigation, but the behavior remained the same.
As a workaround, I moved the call to InitializeComponent() from the constructor to the OnAppearing() method, which resolved the issue and ensured the components are properly initialized with the correct data.
My question is: Are there any potential downsides or pitfalls to calling InitializeComponent() from OnAppearing() instead of the constructor? I’m concerned about whether this approach could lead to any unintended consequences or performance issues down the line.
Would appreciate any insights or recommendations.

You should leave InitializeComponent in the constructor.  Why don't you make your service call in OnAppearing instead?

Because the control is coming from different library and service call is inside the control only.

Usually we use InitializeComponent in the constructor, it is not recommended to use it in OnAppearing. Initializing the control consumes performance.
